# Issues positionning svg using background method

Tags: html, css, svg, background, css-position

I tried positionning a svg file using background method however it seems like I can't stick it to the right side.

Is there something I missed ? I try hard to understand positionning but everytime I think I get it, something new come up.

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/NMD5p/

```
            <ul id="menu">
              <li class="icon-svg">
                <a href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>

body {
background:#5a5a5a;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
}

ul {
list-style:none;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}

#menu {
position:relative;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
right:0;
z-index:999;
}

li.icon-svg a {
background:url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12091580/rwdicon/icon-menu.svg) 0 center no-repeat;
padding-left:1.9em;  
text-align:center;
height:2em;
width:2em;
content:'';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the float property on the menu Element.

```
#menu {
position:relative;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
right:0;
z-index:999;
float:right;
}
```

More info here: http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.field.background.html

Comment: Please link to a reputable source (see http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Will do, I blame google's ranking system haha.
Here's another css reference site: http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.index.html

I have a reference printed book myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `#menu` to this:

```
#menu {
    float:right;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NMD5p/1/